# Laravel Access to XMLHttpRequest error how to fix

Tags: xmlhttprequest, laravel-7

I have a Laravel 7 application and I'm trying to access an external URL in a Bootstrap model window. When I use the below jQuery function, on button click, I want to load the model and show the external website.

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').load('http://***.com');
});
```

I get the bellow error.

> ```
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://****' from origin 'http://****' 
> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to 
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is 
> not allowed for a preflight request.
> ```

I have searched and found one solution to use middleware. I created the middleware file in `app\http\Middleware\Cors.php`.

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 
            'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 
            'Accept,Authorization,Content-Type');
}
```

After that I have added the following in `app\http\Kernel.php`.

```
protected $middleware = [
....
...
\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, 
    ];
```

But I still get the same error. How can I fix this error?

Comment: do you have access to The external URL? If No then you need to open it in the iframe. As you can not access a CORS disabled site in your application directly. If Yes then add the these in the external site.
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: desired_site_url');`
`header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type' ); `

Comment: actually I am planning to integrate social login, when I click on any social login button, I want to open that site login as a page in the body of model, I can access that page via Jquery body.load method but as I wrote I am getting error

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 7 has been released in March and provides built-in support for CORS so developers don't need to use third-party packages to enable CORS in their Laravel apps.

You can use config/cors.php file for your cors settings.

For more details please follow the link - https://www.techiediaries.com/laravel/laravel-7-6-cors-example-and-tutorial/

Comment: In your example you use barryvdh/laravel-cors while you wrote here "don't need to use third-party packages" does barryvdh/laravel-cors is thrid party package?

also I want to access the external website URL in model window, how can I do that an API?

Comment: Please read the article carefully.

Laravel 7 includes first-party support for configuring Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) OPTIONS request responses by integrating the popular Laravel CORS package written by Barry vd. Heuvel. A new cors configuration is included in the default Laravel application skeleton.


For Laravel 6, you need that package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can I use it without API?
I want to open URL in body of model

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't explicitly mention it I'll assume you didn't do this:
you have to enable CORS for every route you want to use it with.

According to:

https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Answer (score 0):

There can be CORS on Both side on 
1 API side at  external URL. ( this you cannot change)
2 At  your bootstrap Laravel application.( this you can change)

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').load('http://***.com');
});
```

This is just a Jquery code. Can you convert this code to some server side language like php?
Remember CORS  can be overridden by server side code.